Problems with enabling ARM secure boot feature on allwinner t113-s3 SoC
My goal is to enable arm secure boot feature on t113-s3 SoC. To do it, I need to burn a hash of a RSA2048 public key to efuse(One-time-programmable memory). My questions are:

How is arm core connected to this efuses (another name Security ID/SID) and what it has to do with registers (if it has to do with them in a first place) ? (I understand that this is soc specific, but maybe someone knows about t113 or suggests a common way how this is done on other soc's)
How can I write (burn) to these efuses? Are there certain CPU commands to do this?

I am aware of two ways of burning efuse:
a. Connecting to a device via USB in a FEL mode or other tools that require USB connection (allwinner tools).
b. Burning during U-boot spl.
Since our PCB does not contain a physical USB port and mainline u-boot has not fuse burning support for t113-s3, I want to be able to write bare-metal code (and then possibly add it to u-boot) for burning these fuses.
Would appreciate any information on this topic. Maybe someone knows particularly about t113 SID map, that would be great!

Similar efuses on Microchip/Atmel SoCs are programmed through a Secure Fuse Controller. Ordinary memory read/write operations are used to access the memory-mapped registers of this SFC. But a "key" must first be written to the controller to unlock access. The web page you linked does seem to describe versions  of a similar Allwinner "controller" and its registers. You probably need to consult Allwinner documentation for accurate info. But documents for security modes typically require an NDA, so details on such topics will be limited online (as you have already encountered).
